# Creating global header and footer in FeinCMS

Tags: python, feincms

Is there a simple way to create a global FeinCMS-editable header and footer for FeinCMS pages?

I've used Django-CMS in the past, which supports rendering content from named regions in a named page, allowing child pages to inherit a base template that refers to a "footer" region in a "global-footer" page, rendering the same footer on all child pages.

I can't find any similar feature in FeinCMS. How would I accomplish the same thing with FeinCMS?

Comment: You can define regions as inherited, so a subpage renders a e.g. header and footer region like defined in his parent page. I think this feature is not very well documented, but it is used in [this example](http://www.feinheit.ch/media/labs/feincms/page.html?highlight=inherited).